# Error in http connection org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to <ip address> refused

Tags: android, httphostconnectexception

I have implemented one Android application, which contains remote connection.
My code is as follow: I am testing my app in my mobile device but I am getting error like:

```
Error in http connection org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to 127.0.0.1 refused
```

I have tried *127.0.0.1*, *10.0.2.2* and *my pc's ip address* too, but nothing is working out.

```
    String url = "http://127.0.0.1/test.php";
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: http://10.0.2.2:PORT_NUMBER/test.php
and check your port number